# Entity Framework Core, return oneday data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core to get one day's data. This is my solution:

```cs
DateTime someTime;
var q = db.Objects
          .Where(x => x.Time.Day == someTime.Day)
```

But it will get all days of the month. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I read the msdn and i found a property of DateTime :`Date`
It's will with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Here is my code

```
 DateTime someTime;
   var q = db.Objects
                        .Where(x => x.Time.Date == someTime.Date)
```

Comment: Unless the `Time` column is a `date` this will result in suboptimal performance. Some databases won't be able to use any indexes that cover the `Time` field. that's because indexes are created from the original values, not the results of operations like `cast(Time as Date)`. SQL Server can, but it can't use the statistics for the values.

Comment: There are several duplicate questions. The fastest option is `x.Time >=someTime.Date && x.Time < someTime.Date.AddDays(1)`.